# Bash - how to convert lines into a single line of quoted values

Tags: bash, awk, replace

Given a list of values returned by a previous command:

```
ABC-55080
ABC-55060
ABC-55040
ABC-55035
ABC-55030
ABC-55025
ABC-55020
```

I want to get a single-lined list of quoted values:

```
("ABC-55060", "ABC-55040", "ABC-55035", "ABC-55030", "ABC-55025", "ABC-55020")
```

I've tried to do this using awk:

```
cat input_list.csv | awk '{print}' ORS='", "'
```

But what I get is the list without the opening and closing quotes:

```
ABC-55060", "ABC-55040", "ABC-55035", "ABC-55030", "ABC-55025", "ABC-55020
```

How can achieve this?

Comment: This might help: `awk '{$1=$1; print "(\""  $0 "\")"}' OFS='", "' RS='' file`

Comment: or this: `awk 'BEGIN{printf "(\""} $1=$1; END{printf "\")"}' OFS='", "' RS='' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{o=o s "\""$0"\""; s=", "} END{print "(" o ")"}' file
("ABC-55080", "ABC-55060", "ABC-55040", "ABC-55035", "ABC-55030", "ABC-55025", "ABC-55020")
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. Written and tested in link
https://ideone.com/zO1eYf

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  s1="\""
  OFS=", "
}
FNR>1{
  val=(val?val OFS:"")s1 $0 s1
}
END{
  print "(" val ")"
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** In `BEGIN` section setting value of variable s1 as `"` and setting output field separator as `,`  here. Then coming to main program block checking condition if line is greater than `1` then keep adding that line's value to variable val with wrapping it's value with `s1`. In `END` block of this program printing value of val with adding `(` and `)` before and after val value respectively.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*/"&",/;1s/^/(/;$s/,$/)/' input_list.csv  | tr -d "\n"
```

When your inputfile is used as an example and actually you want to process the output of a stream, you can use

```
cat input_list.csv | xargs -I"{}" printf '"%s", ' "{}" | sed 's/^/(/; s/, $/)\n/'
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available/acceptable.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

ed -s input_list.csv <<-'EOF'
    g/./s/^/"/\
    s/$/", /
    1,$j
    s/^/(/
    s/,[[:space:]]$/)/
    ,p
    Q
EOF
```

- Change `Q` to `w` if you want to edit the file-inplace.